# how to Add an existing file to google drive using php?

Tags: php, file-upload, google-drive-api

I have added a new file on google drive using the following code already.

```
<?php

// inclusione delle librerie del client
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_DriveService.php';

// istanza dell'oggetto di classe relativo al client
$drive = new Google_Client();

// credenziali per l'autenticazione
$drive->setClientId('id');
$drive->setClientSecret('secret');
$drive->setRedirectUri('urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob');
$drive->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'));

// istanza dell'oggetto di classe relativo al servizio
$gdrive = new Google_DriveService($drive);

// salvataggio del token in una variabile
$_GET['code']= 'code';

// memorizzazione del token in un file
file_put_contents('token.json', $drive->authenticate());

// lettura delle informazioni contenute nel file
$drive->setAccessToken(file_get_contents('token.json'));

// istanza dell'oggetto di classe relativo al file per i test
$doc = new Google_DriveFile();

// intestazioni per il file di test
$doc->setTitle('Test Progetto Drive');
$doc->setDescription('Documento di prova');
$doc->setMimeType('text/plain');

// lettura del contenuto del file e restituzione sotto forma di stringa
$content = file_get_contents('progettodrive.txt');

// generazione del file per il test
$output = $gdrive->files->insert($doc, array(
'data' => $content,
'mimeType' => 'text/plain',
));

// stampa del risultato
print_r($output);

?>
```

What should I change if I wanna add an existing file? for ecample I want to add a pdf that I already have in a folder, What I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to move a file into a folder. In which case you can use the [drive.parents.insert](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/parents/insert) method. Please see the PHP example on that page for a full example, but your API call will look something like:

```
$service->parents->insert($fileId, $newParent);
```

Comment: What's $fileId and $newparent? Is the first one the name of the file? and newParent? I don't completely understand the above code.

Comment: Please see the full sample in the linked document.